# vue+laravel - prerender-spa-plugin для laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix, prerender

Я сделал большое приложение на laravel + vue 2.5 с использованием SPA. Я хотел сделать SSR, но у меня были проблемы с установкой `php V8js`, да и хостинг не поддерживает ни `V8js`, ни `nodejs`. Потом я нашел [prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin)

Но с ним у меня возникли небольшие проблемы.
Вот мой `webpack.mix.js`

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const PrerenderSPAPlugin = require("prerender-spa-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const Renderer = PrerenderSPAPlugin.PuppeteerRenderer;

mix
  // make main bundle in public folder
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .version()

  // make bundle for prerendering
  .js('resources/js/app.js', '/prerender/')
  .webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      // copy index.html to public/prerender for PrerenderSPAPlugin
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [{
          from: path.join(__dirname, '/resources/views/index.html'),
          to: path.join(__dirname, '/public/prerender/index.html')
        }, ],
      }),
      // // == PRERENDER SPA PLUGIN == //
      new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
        staticDir: path.join(__dirname, '/public/prerender'), // 
        routes: ['/', '/sellers', '/birds', '/account/eggs'],
      })
    ]
  });

if (process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() !== 'production') {
  mix
    .sourceMaps(true, 'source-map')
    .options({
      hmrOptions: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8080
      }
    });
}
```

И после запуска `npm run dev` создается директория `prerender` с файлом `index.html` с отрендеренной страницей и директориями с названиями роутов по типу `birds/index.html`.

Вопрос: Как использовать это в laravel? Обычно я использовал редирект со всех роутов на `index.blade.php`, но здесь, как я понимаю нужно открывать prerender,а потом как-то его подменять на `index.balde.php`? Или как?

Вот мой `web.php`

```js
Route::any('/{any}', function() {
  // for standart
  return view('index');
  
  // for prerender
  return File::get(public_path().
    '/prerender/index.html');
})-> where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не совсем решение проблемы в моём вопросе.
Я нашел другой способ использовать prereder на сайте -
https://github.com/codebar-ag/laravel-prerender

Вам нужно установить его, как показано в инструкции. еще нужно добавить в `config/app.php` в `Providers` такую строку

```js
CodebarAg\LaravelPrerender\LaravelPrerenderServiceProvider::class
```

В документации этого почему-то нет, и при установке не добавилось.

После этого заливаем проект на сервер и выполняем такую команду
`curl -A Googlebot https://example.com` - она вернёт html, который по идее должен быть отрендерен